# Acceso FTP mediante cmd

Tags: iis, cmd, ftp, upload

Veréis estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de acceder a mi directorio ftp mediante linea de comandos.

`ftp> open ejemplo.com 46256
 Conectado a ejemplo.com
 220 Microsoft FTP Service
 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
 Usuario (ejemplo.com:(none)): iniciosesion
 331 Password required
 Contraseña:
 230 User logged in.
 ftp>put mifichero.txt
 501 Server cannot accept argument.
 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.`

Concretamente en el ejemplo que os pongo lo que intento es introducir un fichero en que está en mi máquina local al servidor pero el error 501 me aparece con todos los comandos que intento, ya sea dir, ls, get...
Además se queda eternamente en la última línea y obviamente no hace nada. No sé si el problema estará en el puerto en que está configurado el servidor FTP pero no puedo dejarlo en el 21 por defecto.

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso a la configuración del servidor FTP? ¿Tu servidor es IIS ? ¿Te estas conectando desde la LAN o Internet?

Comment: Buenas tardes Alejandro, antes de nada gracias por contestar, si que tengo acceso a la configuración del FTP, es un iis y me estoy intentando contactar desde internet.

Comment: Puede ser que estés usando FTP en modo activo y el Firewall está bloqueando la conexión, checa http://blog.xpress.com.mx/2014/01/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-modo-pasivo-y-activo-en-el-servicio-de-ftp/ has intentando conectarte con un cliente FTP como Fillezilla ?